# A render problem of a plane with modifiers (blender cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, displacement

I'm following a tutorial from Blender Guru "Clouds Tutorial for Blender Cycles" and I'm blocked at the part of the render. I use a plane with 3 modifiers to create clouds but there is a part of my plane that doesn't show up in the render. 
Could someone tell me where the problem comes from please?

Thanks.

N.B. : I already checked the display modifier in viewport.

[image: my render]

[image: blender guru render]

Comment: Have you tried contacting Andrew Price about this?

Comment: Someone just help me to resolve my problem. In fact i just needed to modify the thickness of a modifier. Thanks for you answer.